# Notification not sent by JobService

Tags: android, job-scheduling

So I have a notification set up in my `JobService.class` and I know for sure that it works. The problem is that I don't think my `JobService` is ever getting called. I want my app to check the database every couple hours and if it matches certain criterias it will send a notification. I start my `JobService` like this in my `MainActivity`:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, JobService.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(6484, componentName)
            .setPeriodic(1000 * 60 * 15)
            .build();

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    if (scheduler != null) {
        scheduler.schedule(info);
    }
```

And this is my `JobService` since it's too long. I cut off the code for the notification parts because it's too long.

```
@Override
 public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
 {//when it matches the criteria and the notification is sent

jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    if (databaseReference != null && valueEventListener != null) {
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }

    return false;
}
```

PS. I'm sure my notification works because before I was using the Service class and it would send the notification. I just had to switch because it would not check for updates in the background.

Why?

Comment: If you are targeting SDK 26 the notification API changed and notifications will not display if you did not provide a channel for it. In developer options, you can tick "Show notification channel warnings" which will display a toast when this is the case. Otherwise I don't think we have enough to go on here.

Comment: I actually have I just didn't post it again. I think it's the job not being called. IfI you want I can post the whole code but as an image because it is quite long.

Comment: Add some stdouts in the job and you'll know if its called or not